# Loss of result precision from function convereted from numpy/TFv1 to PyTorch

Tags: numpy, pytorch, tensorflow1.15

I am trying to move a model from Tf1 to Torch.
The model is quite involved and I have been unable to get a portion of it to work. In particular, I have found that a function appears to return a result in PyTorch that is around 10% off the result the equivalent function in Tensorflow or Numpy.

I believe that this 10% difference is an error that impacts my loss function and prevents the model from learning.

I have isolated the function here and show both the torch and numpy ‘equivalents’. Attached is a link to the torch model and the comparison data needed. Below are two code segments. I believe the Numpy result is the better one because it both agrees the Tensorflow v1 result to an accuracy of 10e-05 and in the model I'm dealing with, this function trains successfully when the Torch equivalent does not.

My question is: how come the Numpy function returns better results than the Torch function and is there away of arranging the Torch function so it has accuracy closer to the Numpy function.

Regards,

Simon

The data needed to run this review is saved here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lClIUWuHDGtibSXN2h5X-cyMaalU-cbX/view?usp=sharing

The full torch model is saved in a pickle for use with torch.load:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bFJYC5bHme7YmIbqTOjaxXvd-yrKczxH/view?usp=sharing

The data load and two functions:

```py
with open('recovered_autoencoder_network.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    recovered_autoencoder_network = pickle.load(f)

# parameters needed for this issue
params: Dict[str, Any] = {'weight_precision': torch.float64,
                          'sindy_precision': torch.float64,
                          'target_device': 'cuda'}

sindy_autoencoder = torch.load('saved_model.pkl')
sindy_autoencoder.to(params['target_device'])

# this is a version of the 'problem' function in torch.
def calculate_first_and_second_derivative_with_torch(input_and_derivatives, stack):

    x, dx, ddx = input_and_derivatives

    layer_count = len(stack)

    for i in range(layer_count - 1):
        x = torch.mm(x, stack[i].weights) + stack[i].bias
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        dx_prev = torch.mm(dx, stack[i].weights)
        sigmoid_first_derivative = torch.mul(x, 1 - x)
        sigmoid_second_derivative = torch.mul(sigmoid_first_derivative, 1 - 2 * x)
        dx = torch.mul(sigmoid_first_derivative, dx_prev)
        ddx = torch.mul(sigmoid_second_derivative, torch.square(dx_prev)) \
              + torch.mul(sigmoid_first_derivative, torch.mm(ddx, stack[i].weights))
    dx = torch.mm(dx, stack[layer_count - 1].weights)
    ddx = torch.mm(ddx, stack[layer_count - 1].weights)

    return dx, ddx

# this is the equivalent 'problem' function in numpy.
def calculate_first_and_second_derivative_with_np(input, dx, ddx, weights, biases):
    dz = dx
    ddz = ddx

    def sigmoid(x):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

    for i in range(len(weights) - 1):
        input = np.matmul(input, weights[i]) + biases[i]
        input = sigmoid(input)
        dz_prev = np.matmul(dz, weights[i])
        sigmoid_derivative = np.multiply(input, 1 - input)
        sigmoid_derivative2 = np.multiply(sigmoid_derivative, 1 - 2 * input)
        dz = np.multiply(sigmoid_derivative, dz_prev)
        ddz = np.multiply(sigmoid_derivative2, np.square(dz_prev)) \
              + np.multiply(sigmoid_derivative, np.matmul(ddz, weights[i]))
    dz = np.matmul(dz, weights[-1])
    ddz = np.matmul(ddz, weights[-1])

    return dz, ddz

dx_decode_np_test, ddx_decode_np_test = \
    calculate_first_and_second_derivative_with_np(
        recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_z'],
        recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_dz'], 
        recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_sindy_predict'], 
        recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_weights'],
        recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_biases'])

# Here I access the tensors recovered from the saved Tensorflow model and convert them to torch.
converted_stack = [torch.tensor(recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_z'],
                                device=torch.device(params['target_device']),
                                dtype=params['sindy_precision']),
                       torch.tensor(recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_dz'],
                                device=torch.device(params['target_device']),
                                dtype=params['sindy_precision']),
                       torch.tensor(recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_sindy_predict'],
                                device=torch.device(params['target_device']),
                                dtype=params['sindy_precision'])]

# Here I use the tensors captured from the tensorflow model (converted to torch)
# with the torch version of the function and the layers from the model. 
dx_decode_torch_test, ddx_decode_torch_test = \
    calculate_first_and_second_derivative_with_torch(converted_stack,
        sindy_autoencoder.ψ_decoder_to_x) 

# Here I show the error between the two functions. 
print(dx_decode_np_test - dx_decode_torch_test, ddx_decode_np_test - ddx_decode_torch_test)

# Here I show that the Torch weights in the model feeding the Torch 
# function are equivalent to the Numpy arrays feeding the Numpy
# function. (the weights were initialized from those arrays after conversion to Torch.tensor. 
print(("\n\nWeight and bias comparison for two models (imported from np source)\n\n" +
    "weights comparison: \nl1 {:.5f} ({:.2%})\nl2 {:.5f} ({:.2%})\nl3 {:.5f} ({:.2%})\nl4 {:.5f} ({:.2%})\n\n" +
    "bias comparison: \nb1 {:.5f} ({:.2%})\nb2 {:.5f} ({:.2%})\nb3 {:.5f} ({:.2%})\nb4 {:.5f} ({:.2%}))")
        .format(np.sum(sindy_autoencoder.ψ_decoder_to_x[0].weights.cpu().detach().numpy()
                 - recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_weights'][0]),
                  (np.sum(sindy_autoencoder.ψ_decoder_to_x[0].weights.cpu().detach().numpy()
                          - recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_weights'][0]))
                  / np.sum(recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_weights'][0]),
                  (np.sum(sindy_autoencoder.ψ_decoder_to_x[1].weights.cpu().detach().numpy()
                          - recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_weights'][1])),
                  (np.sum(sindy_autoencoder.ψ_decoder_to_x[1].weights.cpu().detach().numpy()
                          - recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_weights'][1]))
                  / np.sum(recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_weights'][1]),
                  (np.sum(sindy_autoencoder.ψ_decoder_to_x[2].weights.cpu().detach().numpy()
                          - recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_weights'][2])),
                  (np.sum(sindy_autoencoder.ψ_decoder_to_x[2].weights.cpu().detach().numpy()
                          - recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_weights'][2]))
                  / np.sum(recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_weights'][2]),
                  (np.sum(sindy_autoencoder.ψ_decoder_to_x[3].weights.cpu().detach().numpy()
                          - recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_weights'][3])),
                  (np.sum(sindy_autoencoder.ψ_decoder_to_x[3].weights.cpu().detach().numpy()
                          - recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_weights'][3]))
                  / np.sum(recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_weights'][3]),
                  (np.sum(sindy_autoencoder.ψ_decoder_to_x[0].bias.cpu().detach().numpy()
                          - recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_biases'][0])),
                  (np.sum(sindy_autoencoder.ψ_decoder_to_x[0].bias.cpu().detach().numpy()
                          - recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_biases'][0]))
                  / np.sum(recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_biases'][0]),
                  (np.sum(sindy_autoencoder.ψ_decoder_to_x[1].bias.cpu().detach().numpy()
                          - recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_biases'][1])),
                  (np.sum(sindy_autoencoder.ψ_decoder_to_x[1].bias.cpu().detach().numpy()
                          - recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_biases'][1]))
                  / np.sum(recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_biases'][1]),
                  (np.sum(sindy_autoencoder.ψ_decoder_to_x[2].bias.cpu().detach().numpy()
                          - recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_biases'][2])),
                  (np.sum(sindy_autoencoder.ψ_decoder_to_x[2].bias.cpu().detach().numpy()
                          - recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_biases'][2]))
                  / np.sum(recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_biases'][2]),
                  (np.sum(sindy_autoencoder.ψ_decoder_to_x[3].bias.cpu().detach().numpy()
                          - recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_biases'][3])),
                  (np.sum(sindy_autoencoder.ψ_decoder_to_x[3].bias.cpu().detach().numpy()
                          - recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_biases'][3]))
                  / np.sum(recovered_autoencoder_network['v2_in_decoder_biases'][3])))
```

Comment: Pytorch defaults to float32 and numpy to float64. One possibile cause for the loss of precision could be due to improper (precision) type casting in one of the operations

Comment: Thanks Derek - although I didn't know that, coincidentally I do set the PyTorch components to float 64.